# What UK carnivores might I find up mountains?

Tags: animals, uk, animal-behaviour, animal-identification, england

I found some scats that looked a lot like those of a pine marten or otter at 600-700m in the Lake District, UK.

The scat was full of white claw-shaped items, possibly bone, and was 10-15cm long and curled.

The terrain was fairly barren with just grasses and near an exposed ridge, 500m higher and 1km in horizontal distance away from mixed woodland.

Unfortunately I didn't take a photograph.

I'm very new to trailing and tracking, having only picked up a few pointers from friends so sorry for any missed details.

Answer (score 6):

Pine Martens aren't native to the Lake District as yet - you need to go further north to find them (and then in small numbers).

This will most likely be one the more common mustelids - [Stoats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoat) will happily (and greedily) take rabbits, which I believe are your bones.

Without a photo/dimensions of the scat, I have to offer the most likely answer here.  And yes, the Stoat looks small compared with the Rabbit, but it's fully capable of dragging it's prize many metres to a feeding spot.